# How to launch custom urdf in ros2

Tags: gazebo, ros2, roslaunch, gazebo-11, launch-file

I have a package in ros2 named `my_bot` and an urdf file in urdf folder `my_bot.urdf` how can I spawn the robot into Gazebo using a `.launch.py` file